# Ajax Script manager problem

Tags: c#-4.0

I developed one webapplication. In one web page it shows " only one instance of script manager is allowed " error is displayed. But i have to override the master page script manager . Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use tool script manager control to override the master page script manager problem.